# laravel simplexml load file databese curd

Tags: laravel

I want to save some of the data that comes with "simplexml_load_file" to the database, but it doesn't save, I wonder where is the problem?

what i want to save
"US DOLLAR,EUR,POUND STERLING"

```
"message": "Object of class Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Date could not be converted to string",
```

```
Route::post('/exchange_rates',[ToolsController::class, 'kurlar']);
```

```
Schema::create('exchanges', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->boolean('buying_rate');
            $table->boolean('selling_rate');
            $table->date('date');
            $table->string('currency');
            $table->timestamps();
        })
```

```
public function kurlar()
    {
        $products = simplexml_load_file('https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml');

        $pred = [0, 3, 4];
        print_r($products);


        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $exchange = new Exchange;
            $exchange->buying_rate = $product->ForexBuying;
            $exchange->selling_rate = $product->ForexSelling;
            $exchange->date = new Date();$product->attributes['Date'];
            $exchange->currency = $product->attributes['CurrencyCode'];
            $exchange->save();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the error: `Object of class Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Date could not be converted to string` means that you could not save a date attribute in model by passing a `new Date()` object in it, for simple Laravel allows you to just pass the date as a string to the required attribute.

After implementing and modifying your code I reached this working version from it:

```
 public function kurlar(){
    $products = simplexml_load_file('https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml');

    $exchanges = [];

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $exchange = new Exchange;
        $exchange->buying_rate = get_object_vars($product->ForexBuying)[0];
        $exchange->selling_rate = get_object_vars($product->ForexSelling)[0] ?? 0; //0 as default value when returning null from ForexSelling

        // '2021-09-19' as a default date because all the products returns null on data
        $exchange->date = '2021-09-19';
        $exchange->currency = get_object_vars($product->attributes()['CurrencyCode'])[0];
        
        if(in_array($exchange->currency, ['USD', 'EUR', 'GBP'])){
            $exchange->save();
            array_push($exchanges, $exchange);
        }


    }

    return $exchanges;
}
```

Or, you could just check the indexes by using `for` loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($products->Currency) ; $i++) { 
    $product = $products->Currency[$i];
    # code...
    $exchange = new Exchange;
    $exchange->buying_rate = get_object_vars($product->ForexBuying)[0];
    $exchange->selling_rate = get_object_vars($product->ForexSelling)[0] ?? 0; //0 as default value when returning null from ForexSelling

    // '2021-09-19' as a default date because all the products returns null on data
    $exchange->date = '2021-09-19';
    $exchange->currency = get_object_vars($product->attributes()['CurrencyCode'])[0];
    
    if(in_array($i, [0, 3, 4])){
        $exchange->save();
        array_push($exchanges, $exchange);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sharing incomplete information. what you did is very nice but i want only "USD","EUR","GBP" to be recorded.

Comment: It's very simple, just check the currency before saving, please check my edits

Comment: instead of checking, "$pred = [0, 3, 4];"
Can't we just list them?

Comment: yes, of course  by changing ```foreach``` to ```for``` and checking the index before saving exchange

Comment: I will be happy if you edit the answer.

Comment: Check it now 

Comment: I did something different, it was the room, ```foreach ($pred as $index) {$exchange->buying_rate = get_object_vars($products->Currency[$index]->ForexBuying)[0];}```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237268/discussion-between-rateb-habbab-and-selaminko-elam).